# Flash to jQuery using animate

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-ui

I am converting a [flash design](http://9amresourceagency.com/Flash/index.html) into javascript. Its the ball that moves around the screen and becomes the globe. I am using `animate()` function for it but its stoping for a small time period where ever a new `animate()` function comes so its not similar to the flash animation. Any better ideas for it?

Here is how I am rotating it through the screen:

```
 .animate({ opacity: 1 },"fast")
.animate({top:'230px', left:'175px'}, {duration:0})
.animate({top:'310px', left:'215px'}, {duration:500})
.animate({top:'360px', left:'237px'}, {duration:500})
.animate({top:'400px', left:'350px'}, {duration:500})
```

Comment: You should check out this platform for complicated JS animations: http://www.greensock.com/tag/javascript/  they have done some amazing things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been and done that, and when it comes to smooth animation, browsers are still lacking that robustness. Anyway, have you tried queuing the animation sequence? This way, at least browser will not be over whelmed and you will see a better result? Here is a good read:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Thanks